# Не перемещается курсор мыши, если находится над окном приложения

Tags: python, mousemove

При использовании pyautogui написал код для перемещения курсора мыши по определенным координатам.
Если на рабочем столе не развернуто никаких приложений, то курсор перемещается.
Если на рабочем столе развернуты стандартные приложения(проводник, браузер), то курсор также перемещается.

Не перемещается курсор мыши, если траектория перемещения находится над окном определенных приложений, которые, скорее всего, защищены от кликеров и подобного.
(Курсор начинает перемещаться пока не "наткнется" на окно таких программ. После этого останавливается)

Возможно ли решить эту задачу с помощью других модулей или с помощью другого языка программирования?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `скорее всего, защищены от кликеров и подобного` - а как вы собираетесь узнавать защищены или нет?

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что я собираюсь это узнавать?